# Impact of different padding schemes in Frequency domain image filtering

Tags: image-processing, convolution

I understand, that image padding is necessary in order to prevent wrap-around effects due to circular convolution. My set of questions are related to different padding schemes.

1. Zero Padding is easy to visualize in the context of reducing wrap-around effects. In the case of schemes like mirror reflection, I have a doubt that since these are non-zero paddings, so doesn't this kind of padding distort the true spectral content of the image (in the sense that the relative spectral content of two frequencies getting changed ) ?
2. Could someone present examples of effects due to different padding schemes (in MATLAB, mirror, symmetric and zero padding are available) and point out subtle differences arising due to different schemes and possibly pointing out their importance ?

I would be very grateful for the patience of reading this question and giving your consideration to it.

Comment: What prevents you from trying it yourself?

Comment: I can certainly do that myself. The sole reason I put it here is that, I thought somebody experienced and better might share his/her thoughts about this, and from that I would get some good things to learn. I also thought, that a question like this might be helpful and insightful to many students. So, there is no real need to be condescending.

Comment: Ujj, i think @Phonon is challenging/questioning, not condescending.  you "can certainly do" it yourself (so you have the means to check it out) and are able to articulate different contingencies.  it's a legit question on par with asking those with homework to try to do it themselves and then, when something doesn't work, come back here and ask a more specific question that doesn't merely ask other people to do, generally, your hard work for you.

Comment: Fair Enough. Although, it was in no way meant for any homework assignment